# td background-color based on content

Tags: javascript, html-table, colors, background

I'm trying to make a weather table that changes the background of table cells based on the number in the cell (temperature). I'm using HTML, CSS, and js, each in separate files. I'm not sure what's going wrong, but I'm guessing it's the js.

Here's what I have:

HTML:

```
<table border="1px">
    <tr id="temp">
        <td>0</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>110</td>
    </tr>
```

JS:

```
$('#temp td').each(function() {
if(parseInt($(this).html())<40){
    $(this).addClass("NegThirty");
}
else if(parseInt($(this).html())<110){
    $(this).addClass("Forty");
}
else if(parseInt($(this).html())>=110){
    $(this).addClass("OneTen");
}
});
```

CSS:

```
.NegThirty{
background-color: #2b2bff;
color: white;}
.Forty{
background-color: #ffffff;
color: black;}
.OneTen{
background-color: #e30000;
color: white;
```

Any thoughts on what's going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: For me it's working. Have you referenced jquery?

Comment: I'm not getting an error message, the background colors are just not changing. The whole table just stays white. I have not referenced jquery, i've only linked it in the <head> to my .js file: <script src="Climate3.js"></script> - Is that wrong? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

choose your colors carefully!

```js
$('#temp td').each(function() {

if(parseInt($(this).html())<40){
    $(this).addClass("NegThirty");
}
else if(parseInt($(this).html())<110){
    $(this).addClass("Forty");
}
else if(parseInt($(this).html())>=110){
    $(this).addClass("OneTen");
}
});
```

```css
.NegThirty{
background-color: blue;
color: white;}
.Forty{
background-color: green;
color: white;}
.OneTen{
background-color: purple;
color: white;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1px">
    <tr id="temp">
        <td>0</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>110</td>
    </tr>
```